# # character in django url

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having a doubt in my mind about the use of **#** in django urls.I know that **#** is used for commenting in python.
After doing Oauth i get a url like `https://callbackurl.com/#some_characters`.
For getting the some_characters part with the **#** i used the following code in my urls configuration file.

```
url(r'^(.*)$', views.get_access_token, name="get_access_token")
```

My view is like:

```
def get_access_token(request,token_str):
    print token_str #prints to stdout
```

But i got empty string.
So my interpretation is that python treats everything after **#** as comments even in the urls rather than treating it as normal character.
But in case of simple string in python we can do something like that :

```
>>> name="anku#"
>>> name
'anku#'
```

Here **#** is treated as a normal character.
So what do in cases when the url is something like that `https://someurl.com/sometext#anothertext#somemoretext`, if someone wants to capture `sometext#anothertext#somemoretext` from the url.I guess he needs to design regex command accordingly anotherwise if he treats `sometext#anothertext#somemoretext` as charactes , he will get only `sometext`.

Is not the above inconsistent in terms of semantics because urls are also python strings?
Correct me if i am wrong somewhere.
Regards.

Comment: The problem is not with python treating # characters as comment delimiters. Could you paste in more relevant code, so it becomes more clear how you are using your OAuth authentication library?

Comment: i am making javascript do gmail OAuth and the callback url points to my server where after urlmatching the relevant view is called.I already have mentioned the pattern of callback url from google.

Answer (score 0):

When using python to pass a callback url for OAuth, it should be percent-encoded, as characters like ~ and # may cause problems.

A url like:

```
https://someurl.com/sometext#anothertext#somemoretext
```

should be

```
https://someurl.com/sometext%23anothertext%23somemoretext
```